# How can I create an email filter in Evolution for only when the recipient is a single particular address?

Tags: email, email-filter, evolution

I'm trying to filter messages sent to `blah@blorf.com` *only*, and not that address in addition to others. Messages sent to `blah.blorf.com, blech@bloog.org` should get through.

My current attempt looks like this:

```
Find items which match: all the following conditions
    Recipients is bla.blorf.com
```

Since `is` could also be set to `contains`, the implication is that this would be an exclusive test. Apparently it's not. Messages with multiple recipients are also being filtered.

How can I achieve this goal? Is this a bug in Evolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this is a bug in Evolution (evolution-data-server to be precise).

It will be fixed in the upcoming 3.34.1 release, as can be seen in https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evolution-data-server/issues/151#note_598944 .

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, a potential solution would be to filter by regex.
In my case, something like this does the job:

```
Find items which match: any of the following conditions
    Regex Match: Message Header: `To: ("[A-Za-z, ]*" )?<bla@blorf.com>$`
```

Mind you, the pattern to catch the text in double-quotes might need some tweaking (YMMV).